# Pipe read stream returned from S3 using Next.js app router?

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js

I am working on a Next.js (+ TypeScript) project that PUT and GET images to/from AWS S3.

I have these 3 "dependencies" related to S3 in my package.json
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.374.0",
"@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.374.0",
"@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt": "^3.370.0",

Currently, for GETting images, I grab the signed GET URLs for each image in a server component and pass those directly to client (see aws-s3.ts), which means the URL will expire at some point. I want to implement a route ‘/src/app/images/[imageId]/route.ts’ that can be used instead of the signed URLs (`<Image src=‘/images/000001’ />`).

Is there a way to achieve this using the Next.js route handler and is it a good idea?

I followed multiple tutorials for this project, one of them (posted 2 years ago) uses express and a different module (aws-sdk/clients/s3) than what the docs suggest.

Youtube link: https://youtu.be/NZElg91l_ms

https://github.com/Sam-Meech-Ward/image-upload-s3/blob/master/backend/server.js

```
const express = require('express')

// ...

const { uploadFile, getFileStream } = require('./s3')

const app = express()

app.get('/images/:key', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params)
  const key = req.params.key
  const readStream = getFileStream(key)

  readStream.pipe(res)
})
```

His s3.js:
https://github.com/Sam-Meech-Ward/image-upload-s3/blob/master/backend/s3.js

My src/lib/aws-s3.ts

```
import {
  S3Client,
  PutObjectCommand,
  PutObjectCommandInput,
  GetObjectCommand,
  GetObjectCommandInput,
  GetObjectOutput,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner';

const bucketName = process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME as string;
const region = process.env.S3_BUCKET_REGION as string;
const accessKeyId = process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY as string;
const secretAccessKey = process.env
  .S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as string;

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey,
  },
});

export async function getSignedPutUrl(
  imageId: string,
  expiresIn = 5 * 60 // 5 minutes
) {
  const input: PutObjectCommandInput = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: imageId,
  };

  const command = new PutObjectCommand(input);

  const url = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
    expiresIn: expiresIn,
  });

  return url;
}

export async function getSignedGetUrl(
  imageId: string,
  expiresIn = 10 * 60 // 10 minutes
) {
  const input: GetObjectCommandInput = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: imageId,
  };

  const command = new GetObjectCommand(input);

  const url = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
    expiresIn: expiresIn,
  });

  return url;
}

/**
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/getobjectcommand.html
 * @param imageId
 */
export async function getReadStream(imageId: string) {
  const input: GetObjectCommandInput = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: imageId,
  };

  const command = new GetObjectCommand(input);

  const response: GetObjectOutput = await s3Client.send(command);

  return response.Body;

  // node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-types/models/models_0.d.ts
  // export interface GetObjectOutput {
  //   Body?: Readable | ReadableStream | Blob;
  // ...
}
```

The object returned by getReadStream doesn't seem to have the .pipe() method like what the tutorial does. Is it just an issue with TypeScript?

Comment: I recommend you stick with signed URLs.  They are much more efficient than sending it through the javascript layer.  You pay for outbound access so outbound from s3 -> ec2 and ec2-> client effectively doubles your bandwith cost and also requires you to provide CPU capacity to do the proxying.  you can create your function to do a temporary redirect to the S3 location which should make it transparent to the user.